# PHP multiple image button submit form

Tags: php, html, submit, imagebutton

I have been creating a website where my users can rate images that have been uploaded. Currently i use radio buttons and a submit button to get the users rating and save it within the system. I would like to change this so that the code uses image clicks to get the users rating. So far i have the following code however it only works for one image button. Is there any way to change this to get the result depending on what image has been clicked.

Code:

**HTML**

```
<form>
<input
        type="image"
        name="flag_submit"
        src="img/Flag.png"
        onmouseover="this.src='img/Flag_Click.png'"
        onmouseout="this.src='img/Flag.png'"
        height="30"
        width="30"
        />
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['flag_submit_x']))
{
    //Do process of rating.
}
```

Is there any way that i could create multiple image buttons and in the PHP code detect what image button has been pressed?

Comment: Change name to an array `name="flag_submit[1]"`. Assign a different value for each image and you got it.

Comment: And what would the PHP code be to register this?

Comment: if (isset($_POST['flag_submit'][1])) for that particular case, offered by Dainis

Comment: I tried this but its not working. (see responce to his answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change name to an array `name="flag_submit[1]"`. Assign a different value for each image and you got it.
2. Read it as an array on php side: `if (isset($_POST['flag_submit'][1]))`.

Or better would be, loop throu if `$_POST['flag_submit']` and find all values:

```
foreach ( $_POST['flag_submit'] as $value )  {
    echo $value . ' has been clicked.';
}
```

---

```
<form method="post">
<input type="image" name="rateButton[1]" src="img/Rate1.png" height="40" width="40" value="1"/> T
<input type="image" name="rateButton[2]" src="img/Rate1.png" height="40" width="40" value="1"/> T
<input type="image" name="rateButton[3]" src="img/Rate1.png" height="40" width="40" value="1"/> T
<input type="image" name="rateButton[4]" src="img/Rate1.png" height="40" width="40" value="1"/> T
</form>
<pre>
<?php
    if ( isset( $_POST['rateButton'] ) ) {
        foreach ( $_POST['rateButton'] as $key => $value ) {
            echo 'Image number '.$key.' was clicked.';
        }
    }
?>
```

In your case, you don't care, what value it sends, all you need to care about it is the key that was used to submit the form, because there will always be only one key set.

Comment: I have tried this and it doesnt seem to be working. I added the [1]-[10] onto the names of my image buttons and used the if (isset($_POST['flag_submit'][1])) echo "Number 1". When i click the first image the text Number 1 is not shown?

Comment: Have you set up an `onclick="document.form.submit();` event?

Comment: I apologise i had a typo in my button name. Its working great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok its neraly working.... When i loop through the $_POST['flag_submit'] and return the value as you have shown in your answer i am getting random values (14, 23, 24, 29, 17) etc... If i click button one i get a different value every time.

Comment: What values have you assigned to the images?

Comment: value="1" - value="10" for each respected input.

Comment: <input type="image" name="rateButton[1]" src="img/Rate1.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/Rate1.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/Rate1.png'" height="40" width="40" value="1"/> That is for image 1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24133/discussion-between-dainis-abols-and-glen-robson)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick that might be of help:

I have created an HTML page of the form:

CODE

```
<html><body><form method="post" action="show_post.php">
<input type="image" name="stamp[1134118800]" src="redstar.gif" value="red">
<input type="image" name="stamp[1134140400]" src="greenstar.gif" value="green">
</form></body></html>
```

The script to which the form submits, show_post.php, reads:

CODE

```
<?php
print '<html><body><pre>';

print_r ($_POST);

print '</pre></body></html>';
?>
```

When I click on the first image, I get:

```
Array
(
    [stamp] => Array
        (
            [1134118800] => 21
        )

)
```

When I click on the second image, I get:

```
Array
(
    [stamp] => Array
        (
            [1134140400] => 15
        )

)
```

This works with Opera, IE, and Mozilla.

Comment: I dont exactly understand how this is working. What are the values [1134118800] and [1134140400] and where did you get them from. And why is the result of each of them 21 and 15?

Answer (score 1):

The First code works fine for me, the
Change name to an array name="flag_submit[1]". Assign a different value for each image and you got it.

Read it as an array on php side:

```
if (isset($_POST['flag_submit'][1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple <button type="submit"> elements with the same name but different values that can contain the images, only the value of the one that has been clicked will be sent.

For more info, see the specification: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-button-element

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
<?php
if($_POST['button'])
{
    echo "you have pressed button ".$_POST['button'];
}
?>
<style>
    input.overridecss {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(http://i49.tinypic.com/rm2w0i.png);
}
</style>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="1" class="overridecss"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="2" class="overridecss"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="3" class="overridecss"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="4" class="overridecss"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="5" class="overridecss"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Would this work if i already have multiple other input buttons within the same form but with different names?

Comment: depends on situation.. what are you doing with form?