# PHP $_GET doesn't "see" that image has been clicked

Tags: php, html

I have a website with a series of images of products, and I want to have the functionality that when a user clicks on an image, it redirects to a separate webpage with more information, which is generated on-the-fly via PHP. I'm using sessions to transfer the data.

In determining whether one of the images has been clicked, I am following the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815918/how-to-determine-which-image-has-been-clicked-using-php?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

However, my `isset($_GET['value'])` always just returns false. It doesn't get past my for-loop. Here's my code:

```
  function show_product($nm, $price, $image, $pcode){
    echo "<h4> $nm at $price </h4>";
    echo "<a href='product_webpage.php?value=$pcode'><img src=$image></a><br>";
   }

$q = "SELECT productName, MSRP, imageFilePath, productCode FROM productsAndServices WHERE productLine = 'Apparel'"; /***** ADJUST THIS FOR PRODUCT LINE ****/
$result = $conn->query($q);
if (!$result) die ($conn->error);

$rows = $result->num_rows;
for ($i=1; $i <= $rows ; $i++){
   $result->data_seek($i-1);
   $arr = $result->fetch_assoc();
   show_product($arr["productName"], $arr["MSRP"], $arr["imageFilePath"], $arr["productCode"]);
}

// Grab product code when user clicks an image


if(isset($_GET['value'])) // this returns false.
{
   $CLICKED_IMG_CODE = $_GET['value'];
} 

// Overwrite this value to a cookie for use in product_webpage.php
$_SESSION['key'] = $CLICKED_IMG_CODE;
```

My goal is for it to pass the value of `$pcode` onto the next webpage.

Comment: without seeing your <form> tags I can't help

Comment: @Forbs I'm not using a form. I'm trying to follow the answer given by 
user2426701 in the post that I linked. Does their answer not work without a form?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML form elements, please?

Comment: What does the href value look like in the generated page?

Comment: @Wearwolf If I echo `_SESSION['key']` in the generated page, you get zero (or undefined). However, the URL of the generated page does properly contain the right value of `$pcode`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the URL generated?

Comment: `.../product_webpage.php?value=10`

Comment: $CLICKED_IMG_CODE does not exist if there is no value set. Maybe that is causing you issues.

Comment: Maybe try something like this (untested syntax maybe wrong).     $_SESSION['key'] = isset($_GET['value']) ? $CLICKED_IMG_CODE : null;

Comment: That is definitely what is causing the issues. I'm trying to figure out why there is no value set.

Comment: Question, what does `isset($_POST['value'])` return? because the thread you linked seems to use post methods.

Comment: Did you use `session_start()`?

Comment: @PedroLobito I did use `session_start()`. I tested this by forcing the session key.  @Scuzzy Using `_POST()` instead of `_GET()` did not change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: @zhutchens1 what you do mean you aren't using a form, the example linked above uses a form.  To do a Picture click and to perform a get you either need a Form or an href url, something doesn't sound right.

Comment: @Forbs I have an href url around my img tags.

Comment: @zhutchens1 ok then right before the isset do a `var_dump($_GET)` to see what input you are getting.